# How to write a mongoDB query to link nested data?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The collection structure is shown below, we have two collections we call them "A"(blue) and "B"(black). Each layer will have "_id"(object ID), for "A", the all the inner layer will have `_parentNode` attribute except the outter layer shown below, the outter layer of "A" will have attribute `_organisationId` which should link to collection "B" **but we dont know which layer of "B" it will connected to**. And for collection "B", it is same layout like "A", only the outter layer don't have anything to link, thus, won't have `_parentOrd` attribute.

[image]
[image]

What I need is to create a list of parent children relationship like:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "1"
    },
    "name": "A Inc",
    "children": [
       {"$oid": "2"},{"$oid": "3"}],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "2"
    },
    "name": "ACS",
    "children": [{"$oid": "4"}],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "3"
    },
    "name": "ABC Inc",
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
   {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5"
    },
    "name": "Disney",
    "children": [some other ids],
    "kind": "Channel"
  },
...
]
```

Note: for "A" collection, it have `kind` attribute whereas "B" don't have, is there any way to add `kind` to "B" collection? If not just use `kind:Organisation`.

This is my current implementation, but it doesn't work as what i expected.

```js
let orgs = db
  .B.aggregate([
    {
      $graphLookup: {
        from: "B",
        startWith: "$_id",
        connectFromField: "_id",
        connectToField: "_parentOrg",
        as: "children",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        name: "$name",
        children: "$children._id",
        kind: { $literal: "Organisation" },
      },
    },
  ])
  .toArray();

let nodes = db.A
  .aggregate([
    {
      $graphLookup: {
        from: "A",
        startWith: "$_id",
        connectFromField: "_id",
        connectToField: "_parentNode",
        as: "children",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        name: "$name",
        kind: "$kind",
        children: "$children._id",
      },
    },
  ])
  .toArray();

orgs.concat(nodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested queries can be performed using $eleMatch