# Build a multi head tree with JSON list of children relationship

Tags: javascript, python, data-structures, graph, tree

I want to create a graph or tree structure from raw JSON data from mongoDB. The data points are parent-children related. I tried to create some code to make a data structure and pretty print it, but it still has duplicated rows.

## Input

```js
[
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "577048a0a5f4970b59493861" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5914d7528ed1755954d6e88f" },
      { "$oid": "56675f1446e0324b4566f6e9" },
      { "$oid": "5924f500381e3b5854db8a0c" },
      { "$oid": "5cc64fadcf995a1d6b54e745" },
      { "$oid": "5d71b5f49a311e6fd587e3dc" },
      { "$oid": "599646b5bd0b9864d8e7391d" },
      { "$oid": "5850ae570b242ff1782ea07c" },
      { "$oid": "58e9a01f33d3f1f208e032de" },
      { "$oid": "5546db39dbeafcef63e6efb6" },
      { "$oid": "5fbdad479a311e6fd58812ff" },
      { "$oid": "5cabd38142524178c66be1f1" },
      { "$oid": "5491ddb3d707d710141027c2" },
      { "$oid": "5d66f0109a311e6fd587e12c" },
      { "$oid": "56ef0296a7b280e91b475aeb" },
      { "$oid": "5cd4dabce84cdd76faaf597f" },
      { "$oid": "58e43b26f79ce47642fae5c4" },
      { "$oid": "58252929332df05c01c1624f" },
      { "$oid": "55dfd7d2bb58034a69d563fe" },
      { "$oid": "56ef03976e418ae84779d827" },
      { "$oid": "5491dd8bd707d710141027c1" },
      { "$oid": "5ba2eb071e910a58acf98e3f" },
      { "$oid": "5cf580fb87823d36e74808bf" },
      { "$oid": "5dae373a3c6e806fd3bbb1fc" },
      { "$oid": "61c3a8bf3824dd48d99ab572" },
      { "$oid": "5a2f468069d12b0a0f4cc68e" },
      { "$oid": "5be8de44c052dc326ab1e810" },
      { "$oid": "5c98455267dcef531cbc44f6" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5835f65457eea2852d2bf48c" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5924f500381e3b5854db8a0c" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "56ef03976e418ae84779d827" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "59c87107cdfaa27f5759b107" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a24977405bdd758991bdb93" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "55aef43d03d4ad2343c2e27f" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "56d382a0589377c94614cbbc" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5cdb32901d30d576fe946d44" },
      { "$oid": "5a53e1ac23090e4877973532" },
      { "$oid": "613e86c24faf093afab2c0ea" },
      { "$oid": "62eb0a4456bdf04c7768843c" },
      { "$oid": "5a53ddb8159e7944e0b44795" },
      { "$oid": "606e58ad2f2af36f2219bcc8" },
      { "$oid": "628da1ce238868408a576c22" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "592776bc8ed1755954d6e8d5" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "594c8252381e3b5854db8af7" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "59503126381e3b5854db8afc" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "58e43b26f79ce47642fae5c4" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "59644a45442b1e826dd7cdac" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5965a855b3e775836dfd8d5b" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "599646b5bd0b9864d8e7391d" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "59965edbf39ca264d9dd41ca" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "58ddc042f67c5f75420cc403" },

    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5914d7528ed1755954d6e88f" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a53e1ac23090e4877973532" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5aaf190e159e7944e0b44fe1" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5b15c4adee10e503a6a6d757" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "55c8024609c8cb2176ba55da" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "581bbdfbf0df7f680817970b" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5491dd7ed707d710141027c0" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d54d4fc5937ee123ad60c9d" },
      { "$oid": "5cb7ef9281c9d71d6a82843f" },
      { "$oid": "5d59c4efa0e40d1239ec5e14" },
      { "$oid": "5cf707cde5dbb949ad5cc302" },
      { "$oid": "5d54bd25a0e40d1239ec5d9c" },
      { "$oid": "5c1a9ae870c07e201b3a4880" },
      { "$oid": "5c0ec151a9b73222dfdd82d6" },
      { "$oid": "5de70b4f9a311e6fd587f4e9" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "581bbdfbf0df7f680817970b" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5850ae570b242ff1782ea07c" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5cd4dabce84cdd76faaf597f" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "54fe27cf5c25b1394be6b303" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "6241210f7210ae3af7727813" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "58252929332df05c01c1624f" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5b57b20e8fff7b28249879ae" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d01cc1787e6383735ed12a6" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5988de44d4978b0596152387" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d06bcaaefa930373488e7c0" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5ad6ca76159e7944e0b45553" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5b15e2dd5240347c64223fed" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "56675f1446e0324b4566f6e9" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a0223cc285a000c2866565c" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5491dfa5d707d710141027cb" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5491ddb3d707d710141027c2" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "555560f0ab95c2765d65c3cd" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "55dfd7d2bb58034a69d563fe" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "55cd503216db9f1c385a69db" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5f4f019d0e170b6f23370b53" },
      { "$oid": "5a0223cc285a000c2866565c" },
      { "$oid": "5f6175683c6e806fd3bbcef7" },
      { "$oid": "6289c9d0adb2f54c79e239d4" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a8211ad159e7944e0b44b67" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d82a7063c6e806fd3bbaa37" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5491dd8bd707d710141027c1" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5771fda4d0c907f02785022a" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "57391e8ec1d461090ef7397d" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a53ddb8159e7944e0b44795" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5af905d15240347c64223af3" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5b6cd1aff6056722483d49f2" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d531e95ff66e07233a2bf76" },
      { "$oid": "5d5475e993b2f3707a737d40" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5702f5161c852788280926f3" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5f0b9d810e170b6f2337073d" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a0dfc4894ba750156a47e9c" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "58e9a01f33d3f1f208e032de" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a2472d6f6b76456d074f761" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a2f468069d12b0a0f4cc68e" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5b4e5a958fff7b2824987846" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5546db39dbeafcef63e6efb6" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "56ef0296a7b280e91b475aeb" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "57ce00596dfb923915cf9a7f" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5a24b30df6b76456d074f7c4" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5ba2eb071e910a58acf98e3f" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5be8de44c052dc326ab1e810" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5be9cc9c20a38c39bc4c807b" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5be9d2553863d639bbface86" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c075bd666a1c95d2acc6a3f" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c083f19d011855d2b41d458" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c0ec151a9b73222dfdd82d6" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c1a9ae870c07e201b3a4880" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c3bd69f70c07e201b3a4a99" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c5cd18745f41e78ebfb0732" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5c5cd1a31279d46f7d90a186" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c5cd1a31279d46f7d90a186" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c609d8686e12578ea359383" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d531e95ff66e07233a2bf76" },
      { "$oid": "5b6cd1aff6056722483d49f2" },
      { "$oid": "5d5475e993b2f3707a737d40" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c64ccb086e12578ea359499" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c85a3b56ce63b531de0eaef" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5c98455267dcef531cbc44f6" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5caabb5bc8bbd278c0392dab" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5cabd38142524178c66be1f1" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5cb7ef9281c9d71d6a82843f" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5cc64fadcf995a1d6b54e745" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5cc659bc17629e20e1a66f40" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5cd4dabce84cdd76faaf597f" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5cdb32901d30d576fe946d44" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5cedbb5e87823d36e7480823" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5cf580fb87823d36e74808bf" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d01919b90347136e8e233e0" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d0191dc87823d36e7480ab6" },
      { "$oid": "5d898e340e170b6f2336e8f0" },
      { "$oid": "5d898fc83c6e806fd3bbab51" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d0191dc87823d36e7480ab6" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d898e340e170b6f2336e8f0" },
      { "$oid": "5d898fc83c6e806fd3bbab51" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d01cc1787e6383735ed12a6" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d06bcaaefa930373488e7c0" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d1534be2b4549192d419973" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d153c148c044d174fb9b799" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d153c148c044d174fb9b799" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5cf707cde5dbb949ad5cc302" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d531e95ff66e07233a2bf76" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d5475e993b2f3707a737d40" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d54bd25a0e40d1239ec5d9c" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d54d460cd8ccb13386abd43" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5fbdad479a311e6fd58812ff" },
      { "$oid": "599646b5bd0b9864d8e7391d" },
      { "$oid": "5924f500381e3b5854db8a0c" },
      { "$oid": "56675f1446e0324b4566f6e9" },
      { "$oid": "5914d7528ed1755954d6e88f" },
      { "$oid": "5d71b5f49a311e6fd587e3dc" },
      { "$oid": "5d66f0109a311e6fd587e12c" },
      { "$oid": "5cd4dabce84cdd76faaf597f" },
      { "$oid": "5546db39dbeafcef63e6efb6" },
      { "$oid": "5491dd8bd707d710141027c1" },
      { "$oid": "5cf580fb87823d36e74808bf" },
      { "$oid": "58252929332df05c01c1624f" },
      { "$oid": "56ef03976e418ae84779d827" },
      { "$oid": "55dfd7d2bb58034a69d563fe" },
      { "$oid": "58e43b26f79ce47642fae5c4" },
      { "$oid": "577048a0a5f4970b59493861" },
      { "$oid": "5c98455267dcef531cbc44f6" },
      { "$oid": "5850ae570b242ff1782ea07c" },
      { "$oid": "5cc64fadcf995a1d6b54e745" },
      { "$oid": "56ef0296a7b280e91b475aeb" },
      { "$oid": "5491ddb3d707d710141027c2" },
      { "$oid": "5cabd38142524178c66be1f1" },
      { "$oid": "58e9a01f33d3f1f208e032de" },
      { "$oid": "5dae373a3c6e806fd3bbb1fc" },
      { "$oid": "5ba2eb071e910a58acf98e3f" },
      { "$oid": "5be8de44c052dc326ab1e810" },
      { "$oid": "5a2f468069d12b0a0f4cc68e" },
      { "$oid": "61c3a8bf3824dd48d99ab572" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d54d4fc5937ee123ad60c9d" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5c1a9ae870c07e201b3a4880" },
      { "$oid": "5d59c4efa0e40d1239ec5e14" },
      { "$oid": "5de70b4f9a311e6fd587f4e9" },
      { "$oid": "5c0ec151a9b73222dfdd82d6" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d59c4efa0e40d1239ec5e14" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d66f0109a311e6fd587e12c" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d66f12d2f2af36f22197fed" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d66f1cb3c6e806fd3bba448" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5d66f12d2f2af36f22197fed" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d71b5f49a311e6fd587e3dc" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d82a7063c6e806fd3bbaa37" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d898e340e170b6f2336e8f0" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5d898fc83c6e806fd3bbab51" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5dae373a3c6e806fd3bbb1fc" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5de70b4f9a311e6fd587f4e9" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5e44aee59a311e6fd587fb53" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5e4dc8010e170b6f2336fd33" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5e9e56889a311e6fd587ff9c" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "59503126381e3b5854db8afc" },
      { "$oid": "5be9cc9c20a38c39bc4c807b" },
      { "$oid": "5c083f19d011855d2b41d458" },
      { "$oid": "5cc659bc17629e20e1a66f40" },
      { "$oid": "5491dfa5d707d710141027cb" },
      { "$oid": "5cedbb5e87823d36e7480823" },
      { "$oid": "5be9d2553863d639bbface86" },
      { "$oid": "581bbdfbf0df7f680817970b" },
      { "$oid": "5a24b30df6b76456d074f7c4" },
      { "$oid": "594c8252381e3b5854db8af7" },
      { "$oid": "55c8024609c8cb2176ba55da" },
      { "$oid": "59965edbf39ca264d9dd41ca" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5ed02be39a311e6fd58802d6" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "57391e8ec1d461090ef7397d" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5edd66c79a311e6fd5880363" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5f0b9d810e170b6f2337073d" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5f4f019d0e170b6f23370b53" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5f6175683c6e806fd3bbcef7" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5fbdad479a311e6fd58812ff" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "5fe3bd7a3c6e806fd3bbd9f5" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "60187c220e170b6f23371a5e" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "606e58ad2f2af36f2219bcc8" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "613e86c24faf093afab2c0ea" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "61c3a8bf3824dd48d99ab572" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "61c3b11a4faf093afab2c86e" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5a24977405bdd758991bdb93" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "61c3b3e83824dd48d99ab580" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5c3bd69f70c07e201b3a4a99" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "61c3b84d7d28ec48d8455710" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5a2472d6f6b76456d074f761" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "61c3bb467d28ec48d8455714" },
    "children": [
      { "$oid": "5965a855b3e775836dfd8d5b" }
    ],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "6241210f7210ae3af7727813" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "6289c9d0adb2f54c79e239d4" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "628da1ce238868408a576c22" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "6298322c238868408a576cc5" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "62eb0a4456bdf04c7768843c" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "639643faf06d0004d42b2457" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "63a23108a4243f051c006f77" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "64090ff9903a4604d5e69032" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "64518b0da4243f051c007932" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "64924d566d951e05091e295d" },
    "children": [],
    "kind": "Organisation"
  }
]
```

When there are duplicates (nodes that occur as child of more than one parent), I would want to only keep the deepest layer and remove those other layers. How can that be done?

## Expected output

```
 (Organisation) 5835f65457eea2852d2bf48c
 (Organisation) 59c87107cdfaa27f5759b107
 (Organisation) 55aef43d03d4ad2343c2e27f
 (Organisation) 56d382a0589377c94614cbbc
     (Organisation) 5cdb32901d30d576fe946d44
     (Organisation) 5a53e1ac23090e4877973532
     (Organisation) 613e86c24faf093afab2c0ea
     (Organisation) 62eb0a4456bdf04c7768843c
     (Organisation) 5a53ddb8159e7944e0b44795
     (Organisation) 606e58ad2f2af36f2219bcc8
     (Organisation) 628da1ce238868408a576c22
 (Organisation) 592776bc8ed1755954d6e8d5
 (Organisation) 59644a45442b1e826dd7cdac
 (Organisation) 58ddc042f67c5f75420cc403
 (Organisation) 5aaf190e159e7944e0b44fe1
 (Organisation) 5b15c4adee10e503a6a6d757
 (Organisation) 5491dd7ed707d710141027c0
     (Organisation) 5d54d4fc5937ee123ad60c9d
         (Organisation) 5c1a9ae870c07e201b3a4880
         (Organisation) 5d59c4efa0e40d1239ec5e14
         (Organisation) 5de70b4f9a311e6fd587f4e9
         (Organisation) 5c0ec151a9b73222dfdd82d6
     (Organisation) 5cb7ef9281c9d71d6a82843f
     (Organisation) 5cf707cde5dbb949ad5cc302
     (Organisation) 5d54bd25a0e40d1239ec5d9c
 (Organisation) 54fe27cf5c25b1394be6b303
     (Organisation) 6241210f7210ae3af7727813
 (Organisation) 5b57b20e8fff7b28249879ae
     (Organisation) 5d01cc1787e6383735ed12a6
 (Organisation) 5988de44d4978b0596152387
     (Organisation) 5d06bcaaefa930373488e7c0
 (Organisation) 5ad6ca76159e7944e0b45553
 (Organisation) 5b15e2dd5240347c64223fed
 (Organisation) 555560f0ab95c2765d65c3cd
 (Organisation) 55cd503216db9f1c385a69db
     (Organisation) 5f4f019d0e170b6f23370b53
     (Organisation) 5a0223cc285a000c2866565c
     (Organisation) 5f6175683c6e806fd3bbcef7
     (Organisation) 6289c9d0adb2f54c79e239d4
 (Organisation) 5a8211ad159e7944e0b44b67
     (Organisation) 5d82a7063c6e806fd3bbaa37
 (Organisation) 5771fda4d0c907f02785022a
 (Organisation) 5af905d15240347c64223af3
 (Organisation) 5702f5161c852788280926f3
     (Organisation) 5f0b9d810e170b6f2337073d
 (Organisation) 5a0dfc4894ba750156a47e9c
 (Organisation) 5b4e5a958fff7b2824987846
 (Organisation) 57ce00596dfb923915cf9a7f
 (Organisation) 5c075bd666a1c95d2acc6a3f
 (Organisation) 5c5cd18745f41e78ebfb0732
     (Organisation) 5c5cd1a31279d46f7d90a186
 (Organisation) 5c609d8686e12578ea359383
     (Organisation) 5b6cd1aff6056722483d49f2
         (Organisation) 5d531e95ff66e07233a2bf76
         (Organisation) 5d5475e993b2f3707a737d40
 (Organisation) 5c64ccb086e12578ea359499
 (Organisation) 5c85a3b56ce63b531de0eaef
 (Organisation) 5caabb5bc8bbd278c0392dab
 (Organisation) 5d01919b90347136e8e233e0
     (Organisation) 5d0191dc87823d36e7480ab6
         (Organisation) 5d898e340e170b6f2336e8f0
         (Organisation) 5d898fc83c6e806fd3bbab51
 (Organisation) 5d1534be2b4549192d419973
     (Organisation) 5d153c148c044d174fb9b799
 (Organisation) 5d54d460cd8ccb13386abd43
     (Organisation) 577048a0a5f4970b59493861
         (Organisation) 5914d7528ed1755954d6e88f
         (Organisation) 56675f1446e0324b4566f6e9
         (Organisation) 5924f500381e3b5854db8a0c
         (Organisation) 5cc64fadcf995a1d6b54e745
         (Organisation) 5d71b5f49a311e6fd587e3dc
         (Organisation) 599646b5bd0b9864d8e7391d
         (Organisation) 5850ae570b242ff1782ea07c
             (Organisation) 5cd4dabce84cdd76faaf597f
         (Organisation) 58e9a01f33d3f1f208e032de
         (Organisation) 5546db39dbeafcef63e6efb6
         (Organisation) 5fbdad479a311e6fd58812ff
         (Organisation) 5cabd38142524178c66be1f1
         (Organisation) 5491ddb3d707d710141027c2
         (Organisation) 5d66f0109a311e6fd587e12c
         (Organisation) 56ef0296a7b280e91b475aeb
         (Organisation) 58e43b26f79ce47642fae5c4
         (Organisation) 58252929332df05c01c1624f
         (Organisation) 55dfd7d2bb58034a69d563fe
         (Organisation) 56ef03976e418ae84779d827
         (Organisation) 5491dd8bd707d710141027c1
         (Organisation) 5ba2eb071e910a58acf98e3f
         (Organisation) 5cf580fb87823d36e74808bf
         (Organisation) 5dae373a3c6e806fd3bbb1fc
         (Organisation) 61c3a8bf3824dd48d99ab572
         (Organisation) 5a2f468069d12b0a0f4cc68e
         (Organisation) 5be8de44c052dc326ab1e810
         (Organisation) 5c98455267dcef531cbc44f6
 (Organisation) 5d66f1cb3c6e806fd3bba448
     (Organisation) 5d66f12d2f2af36f22197fed
 (Organisation) 5e44aee59a311e6fd587fb53
 (Organisation) 5e4dc8010e170b6f2336fd33
 (Organisation) 5e9e56889a311e6fd587ff9c
     (Organisation) 59503126381e3b5854db8afc
     (Organisation) 5be9cc9c20a38c39bc4c807b
     (Organisation) 5c083f19d011855d2b41d458
     (Organisation) 5cc659bc17629e20e1a66f40
     (Organisation) 5491dfa5d707d710141027cb
     (Organisation) 5cedbb5e87823d36e7480823
     (Organisation) 5be9d2553863d639bbface86
     (Organisation) 5a24b30df6b76456d074f7c4
     (Organisation) 594c8252381e3b5854db8af7
     (Organisation) 55c8024609c8cb2176ba55da
         (Organisation) 581bbdfbf0df7f680817970b
     (Organisation) 59965edbf39ca264d9dd41ca
 (Organisation) 5ed02be39a311e6fd58802d6
     (Organisation) 57391e8ec1d461090ef7397d
 (Organisation) 5edd66c79a311e6fd5880363
 (Organisation) 5fe3bd7a3c6e806fd3bbd9f5
 (Organisation) 60187c220e170b6f23371a5e
 (Organisation) 61c3b11a4faf093afab2c86e
     (Organisation) 5a24977405bdd758991bdb93
 (Organisation) 61c3b3e83824dd48d99ab580
     (Organisation) 5c3bd69f70c07e201b3a4a99
 (Organisation) 61c3b84d7d28ec48d8455710
     (Organisation) 5a2472d6f6b76456d074f761
 (Organisation) 61c3bb467d28ec48d8455714
     (Organisation) 5965a855b3e775836dfd8d5b
 (Organisation) 6298322c238868408a576cc5
 (Organisation) 639643faf06d0004d42b2457
 (Organisation) 63a23108a4243f051c006f77
 (Organisation) 64090ff9903a4604d5e69032
 (Organisation) 64518b0da4243f051c007932
 (Organisation) 64924d566d951e05091e295d
```

### Current code

```js
const data = require("./dat.json");

function createTree(data, rootId) {
  const root = data.find((item) => item._id.$oid === rootId);
  if (!root) return null;

  const children = root.children.map((child) => createTree(data, child.$oid));

  return {
    ...root,
    children,
  };
}

function prettyPrint(nodes, level = 0) {
  nodes.forEach((node) => {
    console.log(`${"  ".repeat(level)} (${node.kind}) ${node._id.$oid}`);
    prettyPrint(node.children, level + 2);
  });
}

const forest = data.map((item) => createTree(data, item._id.$oid));

prettyPrint(forest);
```

This code produces output, but I don't want those duplicated ids that appear, like here:

[image]

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want it so when one node is marked by another as children it should only occur as children of this node and not in root of the tree, right?

Comment: @Cv4niak, yes, because when i query the data from mongoDB, the total number of document is 129 docs. It should be each row after pretty print, is one doc, and total 129 rows. Duplicated id shouldn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `forest` will get a node for *each* item in `data`. You should only have top-level entries in the `forest` array. To know which they are, you first have to check which nodes have no parent. This you can do while building the nested object structure.

So adapt your `createTree` function, so it only takes the `data` as argument, and it returns the array of root nodes.

I would also avoid having to scan the data with `find` each time you need to look up an id. Use a hashmap for that (could be a plain object in JavaScript).

Like this:

```js
function createTree(data) {
    const nodes = Object.fromEntries(data.map(item  => 
        [item._id.$oid, { ...item, children: [] }]
    ));
    const roots = new Set(Object.values(nodes));
    for (const {_id, children} of data) {
        nodes[_id.$oid].children.push(...children.map(({$oid}) => {
            roots.delete(nodes[$oid]);
            return nodes[$oid];
        }));
    }
    return [...roots];
}
```

This will retain the children that are the child of more than one parent. To keep only the occurrences where that child has the deepest level, you could first collect the *deepest* depth of each node and then only keep those nodes whose depth *is* that deepest depth. In case of ties, just keep the first encountered one.

The following function can do that kind of post processing:

```js
function cleanTree(roots) {
    const depths = new Map;
    
    function collectDepths(nodes, depth) {
        for (const node of nodes) {
            depths.set(node, Math.max(depths.get(node) ?? 0, depth));
            collectDepths(node.children, depth+1);
        }
    }
    
    function removeShallowDupes(nodes, depth) {
        nodes = nodes.filter(node => depth == depths.get(node) && depths.delete(node));
        nodes.forEach(node => node.children = removeShallowDupes(node.children, depth+1));
        return nodes;
    }
    
    collectDepths(roots, 0);
    return removeShallowDupes(roots, 0);
}
```

Call like this:

```js
const forest = cleanTree(createTree(data));
prettyPrint(forest);
```

(No change is needed in `prettyPrint`).

Comment: I just tried after remove those duplicateds, there are just 129 docs. So what remain need to do is just research for duplicated id, and clean all outter layer. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: 5cd4dabce84cdd76faaf597f is child of both 577048a0a5f4970b59493861 and 5850ae570b242ff1782ea07c. How else do you want to represent that? It is not a forest... What is the expected output if it is not this?

Comment: Like... only keep line 97, remove rest...

Comment: line 97? what is that?

Comment: after output prettyPrint to .txt, open that in vscode...I also added gif to show how to delete those duplicated.

Comment: Please don't add an image. Just type the text of the expected output. Or if it is too long, the snippet that is relevant. I don't understand this gif. It keeps moving and selecting. I have no idea what it means. Just provide the expected output.

Comment: I dont want manually delete those, but you get the idea, if there exist duplicated id, check it's deepth, keep only the deepest. After that, you will find the output just 129 lines and no duplicated.

Comment: *"Keep only the deepest"*: so the other parent will lose a child then? The link is lost?

Comment: I think the other parent is also a duplicated parent, please check for 5cd4dabce84cdd76faaf597f

Comment: Sorry, it is the only way to use mongoDB shell for get the data. Can only get 2 layers' relationship.. please refer my [other question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76825472/how-to-write-a-mongodb-query-to-link-nested-data)

Comment: But... why don't you just provide in your question input + expected output (literally)? You included the literal input, so why not the literal output as expected?

Comment: You didn't answer this yet: so the other parent will lose a child then? The link is lost? (of course if the parent is also a dupe, then the question is for the parent's parent)

Comment: Sorry, indeed need some expected output. My bad. _You didn't answer this yet: so the other parent will lose a child then? The link is lost?_ A: I dont think they "Loss" because those parent also the duplcated, when you check "5cd4dabce84cdd76faaf597f" if you delete one of the parent, you can see it's parent is another duplicated item. If you need a expected outcome, I can make that and that just remove the line that are __duplicated__ and __not__ the deepest layer.

Comment: I've posted the expected outcome, please have a look

Comment: Could you correct that? It was truncated at the end.

Comment: Thanks. Added a clean function to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this python code:

```py
import json

with open('dat.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

id_to_node = {node['_id']['$oid']: node for node in data}

all_ids = set(id_to_node.keys())

children_ids = set()

for node in data:
    for i, child in enumerate(node.get("children", [])):
        child_id = child['$oid']
        if child_id in id_to_node:  # If child node exists
            node['children'][i] = id_to_node[child_id]
            children_ids.add(child_id)

root_ids = all_ids - children_ids

new_data = [id_to_node[root_id] for root_id in root_ids]

def pprint(node, ind=0):
    ind_str = " "*4*ind
    print(f"{ind_str}({node.get('kind', '')}) {node['_id']['$oid']}: ")
    for child in node.get("children", []):
        pprint(child, ind+1)


for node in new_data:
    pprint(node)
```

You need to build structure and later filter out all nodes that are mark as child.
Then you can pretty print

Comment: Still got duplicated, `python build_tree.py > org_tree.txt` line 101,102, 127-130

Comment: What should happen if the node is a children of more than one parent? Where should it be? Because your example have this kind of situation and this algorithm only prevents from making them a part of root nodes.

Comment: It is the way mongoDB retrieve data, how about brutal force remove the all the outter layer when we find there exist duplicated? only remain the deepest layer?